# PDO execute problem

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

I have faced a problem .I want to select all rows by executing this function:

```
 public function executeQuery($query,$fetch_mode=null) {
        $rs = null;
        if ($stmt = $this->getConnection()->prepare($query)) {
            if ($this->executePreparedStatement($stmt, $rs,$fetch_mode)) {
                return $rs;
            }
        } else {
            throw new DBError($this->getConnection()->errorInfo());
        }
    }
private function executePreparedStatement($stmt, & $row = null,$fetch_mode=null) {
        $boReturn = false;
        if($fetch_mode==null)   $fetch_mode=$this->fetch_mode;
        if ($stmt->execute()) {

            if ($row = $stmt->fetch($fetch_mode)) {
                $boReturn = true;
            } else {
                $boReturn = false;
            }
        } else {
            $boReturn = false;
        }
        return $boReturn;
    }
```

But when I call it from my index page:

```
$objDB=new DB();

  $objDB->connect();

  //   executeQuery returns an array
  $result=$objDB->executeQuery("SELECT * FROM admin");
   var_dump($result);
```

Only a single row is retrieved instead of all rows.

I also set mode using:

```
$result=$objDB->executeQuery("SELECT * FROM admin",PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

But it still does not work.

Answer (score 2):

The fetch method returns only the current row and sets the row pointer to the next row. To read all data in a PHP array you can use [fetchAll()](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php).

Additionally return-by-reference is no good idea in PHP as it messes with PHP's copy-on-write mechanism and often creates trouble.

So I'd write oyure code something like this:

```
public function executeQuery($query,$fetch_mode=null) {
    if ($stmt = $this->getConnection()->prepare($query)) {
        $ret = $this->executePreparedStatement($stmt, $fetch_mode);
        return $ret;
    }
    throw new DBError($this->getConnection()->errorInfo());
}
private function executePreparedStatement($stmt, $fetch_mode=null) {
    if($fetch_mode==null)   $fetch_mode=$this->fetch_mode;

    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        if ($rows = $stmt->fetchAll($fetch_mode)) {
            return $rows;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```